# Modify Struct variable in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, foreach

I have a struct like this:

```
public struct MapTile
{
    public int bgAnimation;
    public int bgFrame;
}
```

But when I loop over it with foreach to change animation frame I can't do it...

Here's the code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MapTile> tile in tilesData)
{
        if (tilesData[tile.Key].bgFrame >= tilesData[tile.Key].bgAnimation)
        {
            tilesData[tile.Key].bgFrame = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tilesData[tile.Key].bgFrame++;
        }
}
```

It gives me compile arror:

```
Error 1 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Warudo.MapTile>.this[string]' because it is not a variable
Error 2 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Warudo.MapTile>.this[string]' because it is not a variable
```

Why can't I change a value inside a struct which is inside a dictionary?

Comment: Ewww...mutable structs. (somebody had to say it)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a class here?

Comment: @Justin Niessner, why is it bad?

Comment: @Reed Copsey is there a reason I should use it? Structs generally faster because they are not referenceble type or hot it is called correctly.

Comment: @Lurler - Because they can lead to mass confusion. People start using them like classes and expecting them to behave the same as classes as well...which isn't the case (and that is why you're having issues with your code).

Comment: @Lurler: This is exactly the problem with mutable structs - the behavior is problematic.  Most of the time, choosing a struct for performance reasons is a premature optimization.  Better to write your code to be usable and maintainable, and then profile, and then optimize if necessary.  In this case, I doubt this is going to actually be faster, especially if it's stored in a dictionary.

Comment: @Justin Niessner I used structs because I'm used to using them in delphi... I expected them to behave in a similar manner, but I was wrong...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The indexer will return a *copy* of the value. Making a change to that copy won't do anything to the value within the dictionary... the compiler is stopping you from writing buggy code. If you want to do modify the value in the dictionary, you'll need to use something like:

```
// Note: copying the contents to start with as you can't modify a collection
// while iterating over it
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MapTile> pair in tilesData.ToList())
{
    MapTile tile = pair.Value;
    tile.bgFrame = tile.bgFrame >= tile.bgAnimation ? 0 : tile.bgFrame + 1;
    tilesData[pair.Key] = tile;
}
```

Note that this is *also* avoiding doing multiple lookups for no good reason, which your original code was doing.

Personally I'd strongly advise *against* having a mutable struct to start with, mind you...

Of course, another alternative is to make it a reference type, at which point you could use:

```
// If MapTile is a reference type...
// No need to copy anything this time; we're not changing the value in the
// dictionary, which is just a reference. Also, we don't care about the
// key this time.
foreach (MapTile tile in tilesData.Values)
{
    tile.bgFrame = tile.bgFrame >= tile.bgAnimation ? 0 : tile.bgFrame + 1;
}
```

Comment: ...and this is why I posted a comment rather than an answer. I know when the topic of mutable structs comes up, Jon Skeet can't be far behind.

Comment: Ah, now I see what was the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JustinNiessner Anyways Jon Skeet provided a very good and neat answers!

Answer (score 7):

`tilesData[tile.Key]` is not a storage location (i.e., it's not a variable). It's a copy of the instance of `MapTile` associated with the key `tile.Key` in the dictionary `tilesData`. This is what happens with `struct`. Copies of their instances get passed around and returned everywhere (and is a large part of why mutable struct are considered evil).

What you need to do is:

```
    MapTile tile = tilesData[tile.Key];
    if (tile.bgFrame >= tile.bgAnimation)
    {
        tile.bgFrame = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        tile.bgFrame++;
    }
    tilesData[tile.Key] = tile;
```

Comment: I thought structs are not referenct type, but variable type... strange. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Also now I see why they are considered evil :) I will probably change the way it works in future :)

Comment: `struct` are value types. The salient features of value types is that they are copied by value and equality is defined by value equality.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a utility class:

```
public class MutableHolder<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public MutableHolder(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then store a newly-created `MutableHolder<MapTile>` into each dictionary slot rather than storing a `MapTile` directly.  This will allow you to easily update the map tile associated with any particular key, without having to modify the dictionary itself (an act which would otherwise, at minimum, invalidate the enumerator used by your `foreach` loop).

Comment: Is there anything in the framework already that is a generic MutableHolder<T> that I should be using these days?  I've mostly created my own.

Comment: @MichaelCovelli: One could use a single-element array, which has of course been available from the get-go, but I don't know whether any standard framework utility class equivalent to the above exists.  On the other hand, a MutableHolder is sufficiently simple there's not much disadvantage to using one's own.

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 10.0 (kindly fixed by @GuruStron), you can use the `with` syntax to create a new copy of the old struct overriding arbitrary fields.

```cs
mapTile = mapTile with { bgAnimation = 1 };
```

Comment: C# 10, not C# 9. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#improvements-of-structure-types). C# 9 introduced this keyword for records only AFAIK.

Answer (score -2):

Chance struct to Class

before:

```
public struct MapTile
{
    public int bgAnimation;
    public int bgFrame;
}
```

after:

```
public Class MapTile
{
    public int bgAnimation;
    public int bgFrame;
}
```