# Assignment of fields/properties in a struct

Tags: c#, struct, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify Struct variable in a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255305/modify-struct-variable-in-a-dictionary)

Why is it that

```
  MyStruct test = new MyStruct();
  test.Closed = true;
```

Works great, but

```
MyDictionary[key].Closed = true;
```

Shows a "Cannot modify the expression because it is not a variable" error at compile time?

Why is different about the assignment in these two cases?

Note: `MyDictionary` is of type `<int, MyStruct>`

Code for the struct:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    //Other variables
    public bool Isclosed;
    public bool Closed
    {
        get { return Isclosed; }
        set { Isclosed = value; }
    }
//Constructors
}
```

Comment: @Zabba, edited for more code.

Comment: Here is the same question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255305/modify-struct-variable-in-a-dictionary Jon Skeet already answered. Looks like exact duplicate.

Comment: Flagged for deletion (I can't do it as there are answers)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `MyDictionary[key]` returns a struct, it is really returning a *copy* of the object in the collection, not the actual object which is what happens when you use a class. This is what the compiler is warning you about.

To work around this, you'll have to re-set `MyDictionary[key]` after the changes to the object, perhaps like this:

```
var tempObj = MyDictionary[key];
tempObj.Closed = true;
MyDictionary[key] = tempObj;
```

Comment: But then I would need to call the whole constructor again no? There is no way to change part of a struct in this situation?

Comment: I modified my example to reuse the same object instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @soandos struct is always copied when passed between methods, so "whole constructor" is happening all the time (for example when you access your struct by key in that dict), thats why its recommended not to have struct bigger than 16 bytes

Comment: Pretty sure I am at 11 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the struct to be a class instead...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<int, MyStruct>();

        MyStruct s = new MyStruct(){ Isclosed=false};

        dic.Add(1,s);

        dic[1].Isclosed = true;

        Console.WriteLine(dic[1].Isclosed.ToString()); //will print out true...
        Console.Read();
    }

    static Dictionary<int, MyStruct> dic;

    public class MyStruct
    {
        public bool Isclosed;
        public bool Closed
        {
            get { return Isclosed; }
            set { Isclosed = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know structs are more efficient when dealing with several objects that basically contain fields like your struct but if you happen to just instantiate a few objects then creating a class will save you some lines of code :)

Comment: When using an exposed-field struct with built-in collections other than arrays, one must copy the struct, modify it, and then store it back. A nuisance, but the semantics are predictable; `dic[1].Isclosed` will always be independent of `dic[0].Isclosed`.  Saying `dic[0] = dic[1];` will copy the state of `dic[0]` without attaching the two items together. If one uses a mutable class, one can write `dic[1].Isclosed = true;` but that doesn't mean doing so will yield the desired behavior. An object which encapsulates its state in the states of mutable objects held in a collection must ...

Comment: ...generally avoid letting any references to the objects in question reach outside code.  This means defensively copying any incoming data to be stored in the collection, and either defensively copying or wrapping any data read from it.  Structs automatically perform defensive copying when reading or writing data, but the copy operations on a struct of any size are much cheaper than such operations on a class of the same size.  The difference in cost is greatest for small structs, but remains significant until structs get very big.