# Dictionary with custom data-type values, unable to update the values

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over a DataTable and separate out whether an opportunity resulted in a sale or not - but there are multiple avenues for the opportunity to happen, and I want to organise my output by user.

I have a dictionary, the key being the user and the value field being a custom data structure. When adding keys/values initially things seem to behaving normally, but when updating values that already exist in the dictionary, the changes are not kept. My custom data type appears to be updating it's value internally, but when the function call exits, the value of the dictionary remains unchanged.

Data structures being used are:

```
Public Structure ColleagueSlogs

  Public Call As LoggedItems
  Public Email As LoggedItems

End Structure

Public Structure LoggedItems

  Public SalesLogged As Integer

  Public Sub IncrementSales()
    Me.SalesLogged += 1
  End Sub

  Public NonSalesLogged As Integer

  Public Sub IncrementNonSales()
    Me.NonSalesLogged += 1
  End Sub

End Structure
```

The calling function, slightly simplified for clarity:

```
  Protected Function SortData(ByVal data As DataTable) As Dictionary(Of String, ColleagueSlogs)

    Dim tmpDict As New Dictionary(Of String, ColleagueSlogs)

    For Each result As DataRow In data.Rows

      Dim tmpName As String = result.Item("UserID")

      If tmpDict.ContainsKey(tmpName) Then ''This block does not update correctly

        'this exists - increment the relevant variable
        Select Case result.Item("Origin")
          Case "Call"
            Select Case result.Item("Sale")
              Case "Yes"
                tmpDict(tmpName).Call.IncrementSales()
              Case "No"
                tmpDict(tmpName).Call.IncrementNonSales()
            End Select
          Case "Email"
            Select Case result.Item("Sale")
              Case "Yes"
                tmpDict(tmpName).Email.IncrementSales()
              Case "No"
                tmpDict(tmpName).Email.IncrementNonSales()
            End Select
        End Select

      Else ''This block works as expected

        'create data structure, increment the relevant var and add it to dict
        Dim tmpSlogs As New ColleagueSlogs
        Select Case result.Item("Origin")
          Case "Call"
            Select Case result.Item("Sale")
              Case "Yes"
                tmpSlogs.Call.IncrementSales()
              Case "No"
                tmpSlogs.Call.IncrementNonSales()
            End Select
          Case "Email"
            Select Case result.Item("Sale")
              Case "Yes"
                tmpSlogs.Email.IncrementSales()
              Case "No"
                tmpSlogs.Email.IncrementNonSales()
            End Select
        End Select

        tmpDict.Add(tmpName, tmpSlogs)

      End If

    Next

    Return tmpDict

  End Function
```

`tmpDict(tmpName).Call.SalesLogged += 1` is a value and cannot be the target of an assignment - Is there a way to prevent the values of the dictionary from behaving like `ReadOnly` values?

Would the issue lie in the definition of my custom data types? Or should I be looking for a different approach to the problem altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify Struct variable in a Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255305/modify-struct-variable-in-a-dictionary)