# Why is this one line of code different than the two above it?

Tags: c#, struct, compiler-errors

See question in commented code...

```
public struct Key
{
    public string Name;
    public object Value;
}


public class PrimaryKey
{
    Dictionary<string, Key> _keys = new Dictionary<string, Key>();

    object this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _keys[index].Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!_keys.ContainsKey(index))
                _keys.Add(index, new Key() { Name = index, Value = value });
            else
            {
                var k = _keys[index];        // This compiles
                k.Value = value;             // just fine.

                _keys[index].Value = index;  // So why wouldn't this?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Cannot modify the return value of `Dictionary<string,Key>.this[string]` because it is not a variable

Comment: error seems to be in return _keys[index].Value;

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255368/1714342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Key` is struct and struct is a value type, when you access it via a Method, Property or Indexer it returns a copy of the struct instance not the instance itself. Try declaring `Key` as `class`. For detailed information you can search for difrences between struct and class or value and reference types.

Answer (score 2):

It is purely because of your `Key` being a struct. The value is copied out.. which means making changes won't actually do anything other than change your newly discarded copy. The compiler is stopping that from happening.

Changing it to a class will give you the functionality you're after.. but may not actually be what you wanted:

```
public class Key { }
```

Comment: Yeah, I do just need to change it to a class.  I really never create  structs for anything but in the back of my mind I was thinking about 'best practices' regarding when to use a struct vs a class and it seemed like a good idea at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two lines does compile, but they doesn't work. To change the value stored in the dictionary you have to put the changed value back in the dictionary:

```
var k = _keys[index];
k.Value = value;
_keys [index] = k;
```

When you change the value that you get from the dictionary in the same statement, the compiler can notice that you are about to do something that doesn't make sense, but when you divide it into two statements the compiler can't protect you from yourself.

This kind of quirks is one of the reasons that it's recommended not to make structs mutable. With a class both your ways of changing the value works, and with an immutable struct you can't make such a mistake.