# How to update value in dicitonary with struct member error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update my dictionary, but I get the following error on `node_info[edge.node_identifier]`:

> Indexer access returns temporary value. Cannot modify struct member
>   when accessed struct is not classified as a variable.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public bool Validate(IEnumerable<(string node_identifier, string node_descriptor)> nodes, IEnumerable<(string node_identifier, string node_descriptor)> edges)
{
    Dictionary<string, (int inputs, int outputs)> node_info = nodes.ToDictionary(node => node.node_identifier, node => (-1, -1));
    foreach (var edge in edges)
    {
        node_info[edge.node_identifier].outputs = edge.node_descriptor.Count(c => c == ',') + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify Struct variable in a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255305/modify-struct-variable-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @GSerg thanks, how do I apply that to my situation? I don't see where my struct is?

Comment: Your struct is `(int inputs, int outputs)`. It is a value type. You can only set it back as a whole.

Comment: @Frogical why are you using `struct`, why not `class`?

Comment: You *may* want to consider using a class instead of `ValueTuple` which would avoid this problem. Many people (not everyone and perhaps not even a majority, but myself included) will argue against using `ValueTuple` in your public API. Obviously this choice is yours and should relate to the task at hand (perhaps structs have *proven via benchmark* to be better)  You could always maintain the semantics by switching to a class that has `Deconstruct` method on it to "convert" to tuples when necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying a copy of the value stored in the dictionary, so it will not affect the original value. And that is why the compiler is preventing you to do that.
You need to recreate the object:

```
node_info[edge.node_identifier] = (node_info[edge.node_identifier].inputs, edge.node_descriptor.Count(c => c == ',') + 1);
```

The final code will be something like this:

```
public bool Validate(IEnumerable<(string node_identifier, string node_descriptor)> nodes, IEnumerable<(string node_identifier, string node_descriptor)> edges)
{
    Dictionary<string, (int inputs, int outputs)> node_info = nodes.ToDictionary(node => node.node_identifier, node => (-1, -1));
    foreach (var edge in edges)
    {
        node_info[edge.node_identifier] = (node_info[edge.node_identifier].inputs, edge.node_descriptor.Count(c => c == ',') + 1);
    }
}
```

You can improve that code avoiding multiple lookups into the dictionary, but i will leave that to you :)